# How to instruct module to use particular provider in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I want to create a `module` that is linked to my artifactory provider. In my `config.tf` where I have configured my providers, I also have `hashicorp/aws` defined like below...

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.2.4"
    
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "4.64.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
    artifactory = {
      version = "6.22.3"
      source  = "registry.terraform.io/jfrog/artifactory"
    }
  }
}
    
// ARTIFACTORY // 
    
provider "artifactory" {
  url           = "<my artifactory url>"
  access_token  = "<my token>"
}
    
// AWS // 
   
provider "aws" {
  region              = var.region
  allowed_account_ids = [var.account_id]
  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.terraform_role_arn
  }
}
```

When I attempt to create a module using artifactory provider like the below inside a `main.tf` file....

```
module "artifactory_resources" {
  source     = "./modules/artifactory_resources"
  provider = artifactory
}
    
module "model_store_s3" {
  source     = "./modules/storage/s3"
  aws_region = local.aws_region
}
```

I get the following error...

> Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/artifactory: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/artifactory

> Did you intend to use jfrog/artifactory? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/artifactory, run the following command: terraform providers

And when I run `terraform providers` I can see my module is trying to use a non-existent provider...

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/jfrog/artifactory] 6.22.3
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] 4.64.0
├── module.model_store_s3
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── module.artifactory_resources
│   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local]
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/artifactory]
```

I can see the wrong provider is being used in the module, how can I change providers from`provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/artifactory` to `registry.terraform.io/jfrog/artifactory`?

Comment: So both providers are in the root module and not the child module?

Comment: Yes precisely @MarkoE! But I have in no way configured `provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/artifactory` inside `module.artifactory_resources`, so I'm not sure how it's there as a required provider

Comment: If I move the terraform code out of `module.artifactory_resources` into `main.tf` it does work, but I'm confused as to why the module is listing an erroneous provider as dependency

Comment: Ah this post is informative https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-a-non-hashicorp-provider-in-a-module/21841/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module has to have required providers defined as per [the documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/requirements#requiring-providers):

> Each Terraform module must declare which providers it requires, so that Terraform can install and use them. Provider requirements are declared in a `required_providers` block.

Furthermore, there is one really important thing to note:

> Each module must declare its own provider requirements. This is especially important for non-HashiCorp providers.

This means you have to declare the Artifactory provider (as it is a non-HashiCorp provider) inside of the module code, i.e., in the `artifactory_resources` module. The way provider configuration is inherited is detailed in [the documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#implicit-provider-inheritance) as well.