# Terraform error: Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: terraform, gcore

Below is my folder and file structure.

```
.
└── gcore
    ├── main.tf
    ├── modules
    │   ├── gcore_image
    │   │   ├── gcore_image.tf
    │   │   ├── output.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   ├── gcore_instance
    │   │   ├── gcore_instance.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   ├── gcore_network
    │   │   ├── gcore_network.tf
    │   │   ├── output.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   ├── gcore_provider
    │   │   ├── gcore_provider.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   └── gcore_volume
    │       ├── gcore_volume.tf
    │       ├── output.tf
    │       └── variables.tf
    ├── terraform.tfstate
    ├── terraform.tfstate.backup
    ├── terraform.tfvars
    └── variables.tf

8 directories, 18 files
```

The main.tf content is show as below:

```
module "gcore_provider_module" {
  source = "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/git repo/terraform_xxx/gcore/modules/gcore_provider"
} 

module "gcore_image_module" {
  source = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/git repo/terraform_xxx/gcore/modules/gcore_image"
} 

module "gcore_instance_module" {
  source = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/git repo/terraform_xxx/gcore/modules/gcore_instance"
}
```

The gcore_provider.tf content is show as below:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"
  required_providers {
    gcore = {
      source  = "G-Core/gcore"
      version = "0.3.70"
    }
  }
}

provider "gcore" {
  permanent_api_token = var.gcore_api_token
}
```

The gcore_image.tf content is show as below:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"
  required_providers {
    gcore = {
      source  = "G-Core/gcore"
      version = "0.3.70"
    }
  }
}

provider "gcore" {
  permanent_api_token = var.gcore_api_token
}

data "gcore_image" "ubuntu" {
  name       = "ubuntu-20.04"
  region_id  = var.gcore_region_id
  project_id = var.gcore_project_id
}
```

With above terraform script, when I on ./gore/ path, I execute terraform init, I managed to initialise my terraform.

Now I edit gcore_image.tf and replace the terraform block as well as provider block to module gcore_provider. Now the gcore_image.tf script is show as below:

```
module "gcore_provider_module" {
  source = "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/git repo/terraform_xxx/gcore/modules/gcore_provider"
} 

data "gcore_image" "ubuntu" {
  name       = "ubuntu-20.04"
  region_id  = var.gcore_region_id
  project_id = var.gcore_project_id
}
```

When I execute terraform init, I encountered the error below:

```
Initializing the backend...
Initializing modules...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of g-core/gcore from the dependency lock file
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/gcore...
- Using previously-installed g-core/gcore v0.3.70
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/gcore: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a
│ provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/gcore
│ 
│ Did you intend to use g-core/gcore? If so, you must specify that source
│ address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are
│ currently depending on hashicorp/gcore, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵
```

Note that I use the provider module in main.tf and it's working but when I use the provider module in other child module, it's not working.

Comment: Since this is not an official HashiCorp provider (rather a one from a partner), you need to have it defined both in the root and all child modules. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219617/8343484.